# implement projectile motion. android

Tags: android, game-physics

I am trying to implement a projectile motion for my app.To begin with I am trying to plot the points on the projectile.I am assuming my initial velocity to be 5m/s.

I tried to calculate my initial velocity based on projection angle for x and y direction respectively.But I am getting it's vale us NaN(Not a  number).

Also I am trying to plot first 10 points on the path of trajectory but am getting NaN for them also.As the time returned by now is in millisecond I am converting it into seconds.

Please suggest where I went wrong.

```
public void drawProjectile(double angle)
 {
     Log.w(this.getClass().getName(),"drawProjectile called");
     mUx = mUi*Math.acos(angle);
     mUy = mUi*Math.asin(angle);


     Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "Value of mUx: " + Double.toString(mUx));
     Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "Value of mUy: " + Double.toString(mUy));
     for(int i = 1;i<=10;i++)
     {
     Log.w(this.getClass().getName(),"In plotting points loop");
     long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
     mX1=(float) (mUx*now)/1000;
     mY1 = (float) (mUy*now/1000+(mGravity/2)*now*now/1000000);

     Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "Value of mX1: " + Float.toString(mX1));
     Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "Value of mY1: " + Float.toString(mY1));
     mCanvas.drawPoint(mX1, mY1, mPaint);
     }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want `Math.cos(angle)` and `Math.sin(angle)`, not `Math.acos(angle)` or `Math.asin(angle)`. Also, make sure that `angle` is in radians, not degrees.

EDIT: Regarding the "exponential values," my guess is that you shouldn't be using the current system time in your calculations. (That is the number of milliseconds since the start of January 1, 1970; hardly a time relevant to your problem.) You should be using the elapsed time from when your program started (`long start = System.currentTimeMillis();` before the loop, then subtract `start` from `now` inside the loop), or (perhaps better) a simulated time between points. Something like this:

```
float now = 0f;
for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    Log.w(this.getClass().getName(),"In plotting points loop");
    mX1 = mUx*now;
    mY1 = mUy*now + (mGravity/2)*now*now;

    Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "Value of mX1: " + mX1);
    Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "Value of mY1: " + mY1);
    mCanvas.drawPoint(mX1, mY1, mPaint);
    now += 1f; // or whatever time increment you want
 }
```

If you need to use actual elapsed time, then this loop won't do it, because the time for executing the 10 iterations won't amount to any perceptible change in system time.

Comment: this solved some part of my issue.., but I am now getting exponential values for the points on trajectory... so it can't be plotted on the canvas.

Comment: Thanks !! This is what I was looking for... but had no idea... I will implement this and update you about my results:)

Comment: I am now getting the values as number and used the second approach suggested by you.I am getting the points which do not fall under  visible canvas. How do I make sure that the points on the canvas fall in the range?

Comment: @Ruchira - You will need to shift and scale the points by the ratio of the size of the canvas to the range of coordinate values. This can be done using the same scale for x and y to prevent distortion or independently for each variable to get the maximum spread of data.